# New line issue when testing mobile app on a real devise (iPhone - Safari)

Tags: css

I have a mobile app, which contains a manually created icon - a circle with some text and number inside. It looks and works perfectly when testing it on PC; however, on a mobile device - text gots broken to a new line. I am sure there is enough space for it.

My question is - what can be the issue (something wrong in my CSS?), and how can it be fixed (for example, force it staying on the same line)?

CSS

```
.title-circle {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #eb5505;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 0.9375rem;
}
.title-circle-txt {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9.5px;
}
.title-circle-txt span {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="title-circle">
<span class="title-circle-txt">
Point
<span>1</span>
</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you set `.title-circle-txt span` class css property `display: block;`. `display: block;` property creating the issue. change `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` it will be fix.

```
.title-circle-txt span {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block; /* block to inline-block */
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Here is the [example](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/BaNqGEe).